# Why does Apple name the new product iPhone 'se', what is 'se'

Tags: iphone

The latest release of iPhone is 'se', with the appearance of iPhone 5s and features from iPhone 6s.
So why does they call this new iPhone is 'se'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For being that the phone Is going to look like the 5s, but have hardware similar to the 6s, it would be safe to say that it means "special edition" since Apple is going out of the naming convention(s).

Comment: "Second edition" would be safe too :-)

Comment: I personally wish Apple would release iPhone 6sbb or iPhone 6s "big battery".  I really don't care if it weighs more, I'd prefer it actually.

Comment: Given that they had the 6s and the 6s+, I've always joked that they should've called it the 6s-.